# Dart web tutorial problem re-generating the app component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to follow the Dart Web tutorials here https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt5

To ensure I start from the right base I download toh-4-master, the template from the end of the last chapter.It builds and runs fine, then I follow the guide to move and rename the app component, then create a new one manually, however after following the 'create app component', the guide states that reload the page and the app should work, however I get the error included below.

It suggests it isn't generating the app_component.template file properly, any idea on how to debug this?

```
SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on test/app_test.dart (cached):
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

import 'src/hero_list_component.template.dart' as _ref1; from angular_tour_of_heroes|lib/app_component.template.dart at 13:1

[SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart (cached):
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

import 'src/hero_list_component.template.dart' as _ref1; from angular_tour_of_heroes|lib/app_component.template.dart at 13:1

[SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on test/app_test.dart.browser_test.dart (cached):
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

import 'src/hero_list_component.template.dart' as _ref1; from angular_tour_of_heroes|lib/app_component.template.dart at 13:1

[SEVERE] Failed after 943ms
Serving web on http://localhost:8080
Serving test on http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: try to remove the `.dart_tool` and double check you templat path

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename the component file also?

If so the template.dart file is generated from the file that has the component in it. So it will follow the pattern component.dart -> component.template.dart